# Google Spreadsheets: How to add multiple y axis for a Timeline chart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a table with multiple columns. First column is date and the rest are unit price of A, B etc... A and B are on different scales (Say 10 and 1000). If I plot the Timeline chart, I do not have a way to see both A and B on different scales. 
How can I configure multiple y axes with different ranges? Any apis out there?[image: timeline chart]

Comment: Any clue to do so in 2020 ?

Answer (score 11):

You need to apply a "right axis" to one of the series.

Double-click the chart, go to Customize tab, then Series dropdown. Then with the settings "apply to" one of the series, choose "right axis" and customize as you desire.

Comment: It works only for two columns. How to add second, third,..  "right axis"?

Comment: This works for "Combo chart" but not for "Timeline chart".